# Watin - problems with page redirects

Tags: watin

I'am trying out Watind. I am having problems with a Login page og the applciation, which automatically redirects to the main page (without any user intervention). It looks like WatiN has troubles with this. Wehn I Invoke:

`IE ie = new IE("http://localhost/MyApp/Login.aspx");`

The browser opens, it redirects to "Main.aspx", but Watin times out with "Timeout while Internet Explorer state not complete". While debugging, I have found out, that method `IEReadyStateIsComplete`. When trying to evaluate `ie.ReadyState`, its is getting the following exception from ie: "The Object has disconnected from its clients".

I am using IE8.

Any ideas how to handles fast redirects?

Matra

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the problem was related to UAC feature of Window 2008 server. I'have restarted VS200 as an Administrator and now it works OK.